# Can an Internet Filter be created in Java?

Tags: java, security, browser, filter

I have been using Java for about a year now, and am interested in starting networking basics. 
Anyway, can a web filter be created in Java, something that say, searches an incoming web page for certain keywords? 
This way you could filter out profanity and malware.

If So, what are the basics of such an application? (this is on a client, not server)

Comment: What exactly is an "incoming web page"? Do you mean "viewed in the browser"?

Comment: yes. a page viewed or requested in a web browser

Comment: Well, then you would need all data somehow sent to your java application before it is sent to the browser - I don't think that Java is the right tool for doing that.

Comment: I knew the JVM would be a restriction. I guess the only way would be using a proxy and filtering all the data sent through that - a major project. That or just write to HOSTS...but thats too simple (no searching web page) to be very effective

Comment: The JVM has nothing to do with it. You can write a proxy server just fine in Java, but it's going to be a lot of work. For a network starter project, try something that has an easier set up like a news reader or e-mail client.

Comment: You may wish to look to Burp http://www.portswigger.net/burp/ or WebScarab https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project for motivation. They are both implemented in Java. Java is a perfectly good language for this and Burp was voted best web scanner tool in a sectools.org round up at the end of 2011. Webscarab source is available http://dawes.za.net/rogan/webscarab/#current

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this would be to write a Java proxy server, and then direct the browser in question to the server and then once you have the connections going through the proxy you can inspect content.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860362/write-http-proxy-in-java

^ this StackOverFlow article gives some good links to articles addressing how you might do this. I hope this helps in some way, i am afraid your question is a little on the vague side.

Good Luck.